# What are some good examples of phonotaxis in plants and other inanimate beings?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, movement, communication, plant-perception

Reaction to the sound waves by plants is commonly unobserved. A physical movement or chemical release examples due to phonotaxis would be good to know about.